# How create a list with some specific values with pandas?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a very large `.csv` file like this:

```
column1,id,column3,column4,words,column6
string,309483,0,0,hi#1,string string ....
string,234234,0.344,0,hello#1,string string ....
...
string,89789,0,.56799,world#1,string string ....
string,212934,0.8967,0,wolf#1 web#1 mouse#3,string string ....
```

I would like to extract in a list all the `words` that has in the `column3` a float number greater than 0 and place them into a list for example, for the above instance this will be the output:

```
[hello#1, wolf#1, web#1, mouse#3]
```

Any idea of how to aproach this task with pandas?. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: did you want to append only the value of fourth column?

Comment: Thanks for the feed @AvinashRaj. Yes all the value of the fourth column

Comment: I have edited.. yes I know this could help someone in the future! @cphlewis

Comment: Are you wanting a list of all values or unique values?

Comment: What about all the unique values?. @EdChum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' '.join(df[df.column3 > 0].words).split(' ')
```

result from test data:

> ['hello#1', 'wolf#1', 'web#1', 'mouse#3']

pandas syntax in the middle choosing the right rows; `join` all the words-colunn values together, `split` them apart into separate words.

Answer (score 1):

**Correction:**

You can do it with [iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), but it isn't concise as the above solution:

```
import itertools

your_list = list(row[1]['words'].split(' ') for row in dataframe.iterrows() if row[1]['column 3'] > 0)
chain = itertools.chain(*your_list)
your_list = list(chain)
```

Comment: @cphlewis I see what you mean now. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a list of all the unique words:

```
df[df.column3 > 0].words.unique()
```

You can cast this to a list by doing

```
list(df[df.column3 > 0].words.unique())
```

or use the numpy array method which will be faster than the above:

```
df[df.column3 > 0].words.unique().values.tolist()
```

Comment: Amazing thanks for the tip, `unquie()`or `unique()`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, will fix now